# Primefaces is not defined - JavaScript error

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using Primefaces 5.3 with bootsfaces for my web layer. The problem I have is that I get the error "Primefaces is not defined" in a facelet where I use the component **poll** like this:

```
<b:row id="results">
   <c:if test="${not empty twitterSearch.text or not empty twitterSearch.result }">
       <b:panel  title="Tweets for #{twitterSearch.text}" collapsible="false" look="info" col-md="6">
         <h:form>
            <p:poll interval="3" update="sentimentChart"  />
            <p:chart id="sentimentChart" type="pie" model="#{liveSentimentChartBean.liveCharts.get(twitterSearch.text)}" style="width:400px;height:300px"/>
         </h:form>
       </b:panel>
   </c:if>
</b:row>
```

This facelet called analysis.xhtml is a facelet client of the app_template.xhtml template and therefore its root element is as follows:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
                template="/WEB-INF/templates/app_template.xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

I know the problem is usually due a missing the **h:head** label in the facelet, but this is defined in the template like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">

    <h:head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>#{i18n['page.title']}</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta name="revisit-after" content="7 days" />
        <meta name="DISTRIBUTION" content="GLOBAL" />
        <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <c:set var="root" value="#{request.contextPath}/" />
        <ui:insert name="navbar">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/content/navbar.xhtml"/>
        </ui:insert>
        <b:container>
            <ui:insert name="content" />
        </b:container>
        <ui:insert name="footer">
            <ui:remove>
                <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/content/footer.xhtml"/>
            </ui:remove>
        </ui:insert>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

[image]

Does anyone know the problem may be due? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: does it work if you put a (dummy) `p:outputText` or `p:inpuText` in the template?

Comment: I tried with p: panel and so does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there must be some component of primefaces when creating the view. If the if is not meets there will be none, so the library is not included.

If a **p:inputText** is included for example, this works